# Ambiguity in determining the owner of a genitive personal pronoun

Tags: grammatical-case, pronoun, genitive, personal-pronoun

I am new to German and am confused about the genitive personal pronoun. When considering the following sentence (from the Bible):

- Er gab ihn seiner Mutter.

which is translated into

- He gave him to his mother.

From the context, we can tell that the `Mutter` is `ihn`'s, not `er`'s.

However, my question is: **can we determine the reference of the genitive 3rd pronoun `seiner` from grammar purely**?

Since `seiner`, `er`, and `ihn` can all be masculine `he` (or neuter `it`), is there a way to tell if `seiner` refers to `er` or `ihn`? A similar confusion also arises from the following sentence:

- Er gab es seiner Mutter.

Comment: Can you give the context? I'm assuming `ihn` here refers to an object?

Comment: @PMF The whole sentence is "Und der Tote setzte sich auf und fing an zu reden; und er gab ihn seiner Mutter.", thus `ihn` looks like to refer to `der Tote`, i.e.`the dead man`.

Comment: Ok, then the answer below is correct, only context can tell that `seiner` here refers to the (formerly) dead man's mother, not to the mother of `Er` (Jesus). It's obvious that the boy wasn't returned to Jesus' mother, but to the boy's mother.

Comment: @PMF I see. Thank you!

Comment: The very same ambiguity exists in the English translation of this sentence: *»And he that was dead sat up, and began to speak. And he delivered him to his mother.«* (from King James Bible) Here *»he«* in the second sentence refers to Jesus and *»him«* to the son of the widow of Nain. (But in fact even this is ambiguous.) And from the grammar of the sentence alone you can't tell if the mother is Maria (the mother of Jesus) or the widow of Nain (the mother of the former dead young man).

Comment: It still isn't clear whose mother it was. Even knowing the context, it could have been either one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You can't tell that from grammar alone.**

*Seiner* may refer to an arbitrary masculine or neuter noun. Only context tells which noun it is.